# problems with KeyboardEvent and special characters requiring shift key

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, keyboard

it seems Flex trapKeys(e:KeyboardEvent) has problems when user is pressing some special marks ; / ? = + ( ) & * with non-us  (european) keyboards.   Pressing these require shift key.

I am using String.fromCharCode

Any ideas why e.g. pressing semicolor combination faulty outputs  "<"

```
 var key:String=String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
```

> here is a workaround that I am using for semicolon now

```
if ((e.charCode == 60) && (e.keyCode==188)) {key =';';}
if ((e.charCode == 43) && (e.keyCode==187)) {key ='?';}
```

There is also same problem with this FLASH event

> onKeyDownEvent(keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent)

Comment: I think you need to include `KeyboardEvent.shiftKey` to your EventHandler. This boolean value is true if the shift key is pressed, maybe this could help you!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not manually compose chars from `event.charCode` or `event.keyCode`. The only correct method of making user input a string is placing focus in input field and getting result from it's `text` property.

You can make that input string invisible and show that input as you like. But you should not compose input chars like you do.